# How set custom IJobStore to Quartz (.Net Core)

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

Hi I have a little problem, I am using Quartz in my .Net Core application and I need to save the "jobs" information to a local file (cannot use RAM or database). When I couldn't find a default implementation for something like LocalFileJobStore, I created it, but now I don't know how to insert it into qurtz. I would be very glad to receive your answers

How i try do it:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  {
    var props = new NameValueCollection
    {
      {"quartz.jobStore.type", "testAsync.LocalJobStore"}
    };

    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

    await scheduler.Start();
 }
}
```

where

> "testAsync.LocalJobStore"

its "testAsync" namespace for my class
and "LocalJobStore" class name

if I try get type like this (its same like it do into Quartz)

```
var type1 = Type.GetType("testAsync.LocalJobStore", true);
```

it works without exceptions, but then I put "testAsync.LocalJobStore" into schedeller factory I have this exception -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Is the LocalJobStore class part of the same project, or it is it a different project?

Comment: its same project put factory that created his instance situated in nuGet package

Comment: try `{"quartz.jobStore.type", "testAsync.LocalJobStore, <<assemblyName>>"}`. where <<assemblyName>> is the assemblyname of `LocalJobStore` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need set NameValueCollection like this:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  {
    var props = new NameValueCollection
    {
      {"quartz.jobStore.type", "<<full class name>>, <<assembly name>>"}
    };

    var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
    var scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

    await scheduler.Start();
 }
}
```

also after that you can have exception about serialization so add

```
{"quartz.serializer.type", "binary"}
```

to NameValueCollection